# How can I find all occurrences of particular text within all stored procedures in my database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to determine if it is possible to generate a list of stored procedures, where the stored procedure source code contains particular text, such as "table_name".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try this:`SELECT DISTINCT object_name(id) from SYSCOMMENTS WITH (nolock)
WHERE ctext LIKE '%Your_Table_Name%' `

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I find a stored procedure containing <text>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079457/how-do-i-find-a-stored-procedure-containing-text)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look in syscomments for the text and join to sysobjects for the object type and name

[sysobjects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177596.aspx)

[syscomments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186293.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

The stored procedure text (also views, functions and triggers) are captured in sys.sql_modules in SQL 2008.

Try this:

```
select object_name(object_id)
from sys.sql_modules
where definition like '%table_name%'
```

and this to display the actual object type next to the name:

```
select b.name, b.type_desc
from sys.sql_modules a
join sys.objects b      on a.object_id = b.object_id
where a.definition like '%table_name%'
```

Answer (score 2):

If You want to listing  the Store procedure related particular table than in Sql server right click on particular table and click on view dependencies this will listing all dependent item including store procedure also

Answer (score 2):

Try this one -

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities ('dbo.table1', 'OBJECT');
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SSMS here's an even better tool - and it's free! RedGate make a SQL Search utility [SQLSearch](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/) that is fantastic. It will let you search table names, column name, stored procs, functions just about everything you could look for. And it will do it across multiple databases. I love all of the RedGate tools.

And did I mention it's free? Highly recommended.