# Stored Procedure to Search all Queries & Stored Procedures for a Text String

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Does anyone have a search tool, that can query all "Views/Queries" and "Stored Procedures" in every database for an entire server for a string value within the all the view "Views/Queries" and "Stored Procedures".

I need the results given in the query window:

1) Server Name
2) Database Name
3) Object Type
4) Object Name
5) Object Script Text

Comment: This question is off-topic here, but I have been using RedGate's SqlSearch tool for a long time, it's free and works good.

Comment: yes,SQL search works great , more info here :http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I find all occurrences of particular text within all stored procedures in my database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16278549/how-can-i-find-all-occurrences-of-particular-text-within-all-stored-procedures-i)

Comment: Another vote for RedGate's SqlSearch. It is far simpler than writing your own query for this type of thing.