# List all procedures that would pertain to ambiguous column error in SqlServer

Tags: sql-server

Please find the below scenario and description of the problem.

**Scenario**

```
--Step 1 creating tables 

create table table_A (id int not null,category varchar(20))  
create table table_B (id int not null)  
GO

/*step 2 creating procedure and joining those tables.  
 Here you can see there is no alias name specified in select list   
 as there is only one column as "category"   
*/  
create proc dbo.proc_ambiguous_columns  
as  
begin   

    select a.id,b.id,category  
    from table_A a  
    join table_B b  
    on a.id = b.id 

end  
Go  

--step 3 Executing the proc will not result in an error  

exec proc_ambiguous_columns   
GO  

--Step 4 creating a new column with same name in table_B  

alter table table_B add category varchar(20)  
Go  

/*step 5 Now execute the proc which will result in an error message as  
"Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Procedure proc_ambiguous_columns, Line 5  
Ambiguous column name 'name'"*/  

exec proc_ambiguous_columns  
GO
```

**Requirment:**

Can I get list of all the procedures that are being referenced/selected the column name "category" in the final select list so that I can put the alias name to the newly added column in all the procedures.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ROUTINE_NAME, ROUTINE_DEFINITION
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES 
WHERE ROUTINE_DEFINITION LIKE '%category%' 
AND ROUTINE_TYPE='PROCEDURE'
```

Also, check out the answer here: [How do I find a stored procedure containing <text>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079457/how-do-i-find-a-stored-procedure-containing-text)