# Find string inside a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to search for a string inside a stored procedure. This is created by user. So I **cannot** use this:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(object_id), AS MYSPDEFINITION
FROM sys.procedures
WHERE OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id) LIKE '%string%';
```

I have a column which has stored procedures, example: "`execute salarybyid`" and so on, in each and every row up to 200. How to find if these stored procedures have a specific string in them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find a stored procedure containing <text>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079457/how-do-i-find-a-stored-procedure-containing-text)

Comment: I'm confused - you want to find the string within the actual stored procedures or in the column which contains the script to _execute_ stored procedures?

Answer (score 3):

Try like this,

```
SELECT ROUTINE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
WHERE ROUTINE_DEFINITION like '%String%'
```

However, it will only show the first 4000 characters in the editor.

Your query would give the entire routine

```
SELECT OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id)
FROM sys.procedures
WHERE OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id) LIKE '%String%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like......

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) Proc_Name
      ,definition
FROM sys.sql_modules
WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID, 'isprocedure') = 1
 AND definition LIKE '%String%'
```